# From ES2018 async/await to ES2015 Promises . ... timeout

Tags: ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I am trying to convert an ES2018 `async` function into an ES2015 (ES6) function, but I get a timeout, guess my ES2015 version is wrong...but where?

**ES2018 version**

```
    async function connectGoogleAPI () {
      // Create a new JWT client using the key file downloaded from the Google Developer Console
      const client = await google.auth.getClient({
        keyFile: path.join(__dirname, 'service-key.json'),
        scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
      });

      // Obtain a new drive client, making sure you pass along the auth client
      const drive = google.drive({
        version: 'v2',
        auth: client
      });

      // Make an authorized request to list Drive files.
      const res = await drive.files.list();
      console.log(res.data);

      return res.data;
    }
```

**ES2015 version w/Promise**

```
    function connectGoogleAPI () {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const authClient = google.auth.getClient({
          keyFile: path.join(__dirname, 'service-key.json'),
          scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
        });
        google.drive({
          version: 'v2',
          auth: authClient
        }), (err, response) => {
          if(err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(response);
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: ... but `Promise` is an ES6 standard feature, so in your ES5 version you actually use a library? and `async` is ES7+, not ES6, do you actually mean ES6 vs ES7?

Comment: You have your versions wrong. :-) Promise is ES2015 (also called "ES6"). `async`/`await` is ES2018.

Comment: What library are you using for `google.auth.getClient()`?

Comment: In your ES6 version you are `await`ing `google.auth.getClient()` but in ES5 version you don't have a callback for `google.auth.getClient()`.

Comment: (I've fixed the versions for you.)

Comment: @Neeraj Wadhwa I am  using googleapis lib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't translated the `await` of `getClient`. Remember, `await` = `then` (roughly). You're also falling prey to the [promise creation anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it#): When you already have a promise (from `getClient`), you almost never need to use `new Promise`. Just use `then`.

Here's an example with each `await` converted into a `then`, using the chain for the subsequent operations:

```
function connectGoogleAPI () {
  // Create a new JWT client using the key file downloaded from the Google Developer Console
  return google.auth.getClient({
    keyFile: path.join(__dirname, 'service-key.json'),
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
  }).then(client => {
      // Obtain a new drive client, making sure you pass along the auth client
      const drive = google.drive({
        version: 'v2',
        auth: client
      });

      // Make an authorized request to list Drive files.
      return drive.files.list();
  }).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      return res.data;
  });
}
```

That last part can be just

```
  }).then(res => res.data);
```

...if you remove the `console.log`. (Or we could abuse the comma operator.)

Notes:

- Each `await` needs to become a `then` handler (there were two in the original, awaiting `getClient` and `drive.files.list`)
- In a `then` handler, if you have to wait for another promise (such as the one from `drive.files.list`) you typically *return* it from the handler, and then use another handler to handle *that* result (which is why I have `return drive.files.list()` and then a separate handler for converting `res` to `res.data`)

Re that second point: *Sometimes* nesting is appropriate, such as when you need to combine the result with some intermediate value you only have with in your `then` handler. (For instance, if we wanted to combine `res.data` with `client`.) But generally, prefer not to nest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback...  going to test it now

Comment: Up and running ! So cool...  this function is executed inside a Firebase function, using the default Firebase project App Engine service account ( w role Account Token Creator) . This service account is authorized to access the Google Drive API within the given scope...  Well done